# What page size maximizes readability across common ebook readers?

Tags: pdf

Suppose that I have to create a PDF ebook (meaning no automatic word reflow, etc). What page size (width by height) maximizes readability across common e-readers and mobile devices?

Context: I typically create my ebooks using LaTeX, meaning that the PDF format is the only option I have easy access to. It's *possible* to design for multiple form factors, but each additional form factor requires additional debugging (in the form of looking for overfull/underfull hboxes, hyphenation issues, etc.), which is why I would prefer to work with only one form factor.

Comment: With the explosion in tablets and smart phones, this question is essentially meaningless.

Comment: @Donald.McLean Is there a restriction to this question that would make it meaningful? e.g. I'm under the impression that most major e-readers have similar form factors and sizes.

Comment: By way of example - I have 3 devices that I use for reading ebooks. iPad (4th generation, retina display), iPhone 4, Sony PRS-350. All support PDF, but there is no page size that would work WELL for all three devices because the sizes are all so different. Samsung, for example, makes 3 different sizes of its current tablet line (10.1, 8, 7). That's why folks are flocking to ePub - it's *designed* to reflow text to fit the display, not to mention the preferred font size of the user. My dad, at 78, uses a large font than I do.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I see. That's fair, I guess this doesn't make for a particularly good question.

Comment: I've actually changed my mind. It is a useful question, even if the way that the question is worded might seem otherwise. Many times, the value of a question can be best seen by the usefulness of the answer(s). I will change my vote if the question is edited.

Comment: What sort of document is it, if lots of mathematics and figures then you are sort of stuck with pdf see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95600/recommended-workflow-latex-epub-with-math-viewable-on-ipad but if just text then possible to generate epub see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub for a start

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would be extremely difficult since the broad range of devices out there have vastly different physical screen sizes and aspect ratios. Your best bet would be to use a small page size (perhaps 4" x 3") so that users with e-book apps on their smartphones would still be able to comfortably read the text. This comes at a price: e-book readers or tables with large screens will display very large text - although some might allow you to zoom out or display multiple pages at a time.

I would suggest a slightly different route based on [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16569/latex-document-to-epub-or-mobi-ebook-formats-with-mathematical-formulas). Instead of exporting from LaTeX to PDF, export to HTML. Then use a tool such as [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert the HTML files produced to a MOBI or EPUB file.